# How to open Razor template delegate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
Func<Place, HelperResult> f = @<text>@Html.EditorFor(m => @item.PlaceId)</text>;
```

This compiles fine. Is there a more succinct way to open a Razor template than with `<text>`? Just `@` by itself doesn't work at all and `@:` complains that its missing a , or a } somewhere.

It seems to require some kind of angle bracket tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any HTML, there is no reason to use a Razor helper in the first place.  Instead, you should use a normal lambda:

```
Func<Place, HelperResult> f = item => Html.EditorFor(m => item.PlaceId);
```

Comment: Gives the error...  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

Comment: Ahhh... works if I make the return type IHtmlString.

Comment: What about this...  Func<Place, IHtmlString> g = @<text>@Html.EditorFor(m => @item.PlaceId) <br/></text>; ??